# how can I delete a file created by another user using C?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I have two C codes, the  first code is called "Producer" and I run it in the user "A" and the code create a file. The second code named "Consumer", is run in the user "B" and, this code read the file created by the "Producer" and need delete this file after end the reading. Both users "A" and "B" are in the group "ABshare". The file is create by the "Producer" with permission 0660.

When i run de "Producer" code in user "A", the file is create flawlessly and i can read this when i run the "Consumer" in user "B" but the problem is that i can't delete the file.  To delete the file i try using the function "remove ()" http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html

When I run the "Producer" and the "Consumer" both in user "A" or in user "B", the "Producer" generate the file and the "Consumer" can read and delete this file.

Why i can't delete the file when i run the "Producer" and the "Consumer" in diferents users? I try modify the own of the file from "A" to "B" before delete him using the "Consumer" code, for this I use this code: Change owner and group in c, but i can only change the group of file not the own.

Reading about chown fuction in ths man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/chown.3p.html i find this information: "Changing the user ID is restricted to processes with **appropriate privileges**."

How I can give to the "Consumer" code the "**appropriate privileges**" to change the own of file create by the "Producer" in user A when " Consumer" run in "B"? Or, How I can delete the file created by "Producer" when "Producer" and "Consumer" run in diferrents users?

Please, Somebody can help me?

Thank you!!!

Comment: If you can delete/modify files from other users without additional privileges, is there any point in having "users" at all?

Comment: BTW: for {rename,delete} you also need write permission in the directory where the file lives.

Comment: Any piece of workings which you have done till now? You cannot just come here and ask for code to complete your homework. Try to do it by yourself and come with the area where you are stuck rather than asking us to do the code for you.

Comment: You need [`chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html). This allows the producer to modify the permissions on the file. To make it simple: `chmod("yourfile", 0777);`  modifies the permissions for `yourfile` so that any user can delete it.

Comment: That's not about programming, but file privileges.

Comment: Oh, and: who owns the direectory both are in?

Comment: You need system( "sudo -A rm filetodelte.txt"); Then you ned to configure AskPass to call the helper program, which will probably ask for the password graphically, or could have it hard-coded in (not terribly secure).

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Hard-coding a password in program code is one of the worst thingy ou can do! Not only it is insecure, but also what if you change the password?

Comment: put both users in the same group. give the group read/write access to the file ( the will also need read/write/exe to the dir containing the file )

Comment: Hi everybody! First, Thank you all for your help!

So, like the @wildplasser said, all I needed to give the correct permission to the directory where the files lives (Thank you, man!). In my case, the new permission of directory is 0777.

Really, Thank you all for your time and support! And, how are we still in january, happy 2017 for everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Like wildplasser said, all I needed is to give the correct permission to the directory where the files lives. In my case, the new permission of directory is 0777.